Android Emulator Error: [AxiosError: Network Error]
I am working in a react-native application. Here, I am getting [AxiosError: Network Error] in the android emulator, while calling my application specific APIs (which is hosted). But it works fine in the real android device.
Please check the below code block (App.js)


useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://uhbvn.eeslsmartmeter.in/api/users/homePageData')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => console.log('API response', data))
      .catch((error) => { console.error('API error:', error);});
  })




Note

I get the proper response in the android real device for the same API.
Moreover, other APIs (e.g. https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1) works fine in the emulator itself.


How do you get an error about "axios" if you used "fetch"?

I tried with 'axios' also, then that error message comes
